# Non-standard REST pagination approach in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to figure out how to work with a REST api call that is paginated.  The JSON response from each page of pagination has a flag `"lastPage": True` or `"lastPage": False` to specify if you've reached the last page.

In the Data Factory [REST Connector article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support), the pagination section mentions several supported pagination schemes:

1. Absolute or relative path of next page in response body or header
2. Query parameter for the next page in response body or header
3. Header value for next page in response body or header

None of these three approaches seem to describe the type of response I'm dealing with.  What solution would work in this case?

[Here's the documentation](https://marketplace.att.com/docs#/) for the API I'm working with.

Comment: About your request, it's  not supported for now. May you could post the feedback here:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your request, it's not supported for now.
You could post the feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

We can help you vote it up to make product team know.